# Application run failed in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am a new coder on Spring Boot. I read Json File and then I have errors. Then, I couldn't find the solution.

City Class:

```
public class City{

    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

    private String name;                                       

    public City(){

    }
}
```

CityRepository Class:

```
public interface CourierRepository extends CrudRepository<City, String> {
}
```

When I write `<City, Integer>` and `private int name;` and change the Json data from  `"name": "Las Vegas"` to `"name": "1"` I don't have any error. The program save the data and I can see on `http://localhost:8080/cities/list`.However it doesn't accept the String. Why it gives error on String ?

Comment: You haven't showed what your errors are.

Comment: oke let me show you

Comment: Before I write the errors, david gave the solutions. However thank you so much @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your JPA mapping :

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private String name;
```

The `AUTO` mode is generally a counter incremented by 1 at each new insertion.
That makes no sense with a `String` type for the field.
Instead declare either `Integer` or `Long` as type to benefit from that strategy.

Comment: Thank you davidxxx I didn't release that. Before, I had a long type that's why I used it. After a while, I forgot romove that part.